# Why does the system keep in (CHAOS CALMER)15.05 after upgrading 15.05.1?

Tags: openwrt

I tried many times to upgrade the firmware in both LuCi and SSH as well as the cold reset of the router..

But the information still shows in LuCi,

---

Hostname *OpenWrt*

Model *Buffalo WZR-HP-G450H*

Firmware Version *OpenWrt Chaos Calmer **15.05** / LuCI (git-15.248.30277-3836b45)*

Kernel Version *3.18.**20***

---

It's different from [openwrt](https://openwrt.org/) mentioned 15.05.1 in its main page,

*Linux kernel updated to version 3.18.23*

...

and one more problem is,

opkg cannot update,

```
Downloading https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.gz.
Downloading https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.sig.
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
...
```

What's wrong with my updating?